# Creating Tree Layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making a network application where users can change channels and I want it to look similar to ventrilo channels (as seen below).

[image]

Does anyone knows which Swing classes I should be looking at in order to produce this layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jTree` is something you should look into! `javax.swing.JTree`

Comment: From google images it looks pretty much like it . Thanks ill check it .

Answer (score 2):

For Container is there [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

1) in the `Container#NORTH` topPanel (username - bindings) with `BorderLayout` (`EAST-CENTER-WEST`)

2) in the `Container#CENTER` are three [JPanels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)

- to the `NORTH` empty `JLabel` on `EAST`, [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) with text ping:41 on the `CENTER`
- `JPanel` with [JButtons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) on the `WEST` with [GridLayout(7, 1, 10, 0)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)
- in the `CENTER` is there [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) with [JTree](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

3) in the `Container#SOUTH` bottomPanel with two [JCheckBoxes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox) ba using `GridLayout(1, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Also, consider [`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html), a hierarchical view derived from `JTable`. Additional information is shown [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui/4447#4447).

Comment: you like that component, don't you :-) Can't detect any table-ness in the OPs requirement, so personally wouldn't recommend using the Outline (which was rather buggy when I looked at it a - longer - while ago)

Comment: Yes! Its `OutlineModel` is a nice combination of `TreeModel` & `TableModel`, and the renderers are familiar. I've been using it since NetBeans 6.8.